# (Spark) Is there any possible way to optimize two large rdd join when both of them is too large for memory(means cannot use broadcast)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

As title.

Is there any possible way to optimize two large rdd join when both of them is too large for memory? In this case I suppose we cannot use broadcast for map side join.

If I have to join this two rdd, and both of them is too large to fit in memory:

```
country_rdd: 
(id, country)

income_rdd:
(id, (income, month, year))

joined_rdd = income_rdd.join(country_rdd)
```

Is there any possible way to reduce the shuffling here? Or anything I can do to tuning the join performance?

Besides, the joined_rdd will be further calculated and reduced only by country and time, not relevant to id anymore. Eg: my final result = income for different country in different years. What's the best practice to do that?

I used to consider do some pre-partition, but seems if I only need to do join once that won't help much?

Answer (score 3):

In general case (no a priori knowledge of the key properties) it is not possible. Shuffle is a essential part of the `join` and cannot be avoided.

In specific cases you can reduce shuffling in two ways:

- Design your own `Partitioner` which takes advantage of pre-existing data distribution. For example if you know that data is sorted by key you can use that knowledge to limit the shuffle.
- If you apply inner join, and only a fraction of keys occurs in both RDDs you can:

  - Create Bloom filters on each datasets. Lets call these `leftFilter` and `rightFilter`.
  - Filter RDD with opposite filters (`leftRDD` with `rightFilter`, `rightRDD` with `leftFilter`)
  - Join filtered RDD